# How to set different transition times for individual CSS filter functions?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, css-filters

Let's assume I have a `filter` property like

```
filter: drop-shadow(25px 25px 2px white) 
        grayscale(100%) 
        brightness(30%);
```

A transition affects all kind of filters.

```
transition: filter 5s;
```

**Is it possible to only affect a subset of filter functions?** (e.g. only grayscaling)

---

[Here a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jfvnd2tc/)

Comment: I do not think you can affect the transition of a specific filter. You may need to split them out into different classes?